# plesk - no email option

Tags: email, plesk

I can't find email option in my plesk panel
[image]

I have installed mail servers in components, and i see mail settings under server tab but i just cant figure out how to enable mail for specific domain

If i go to `webmail.pedjaapps.net` i opens default home page
`webmail` subdomain points to my servers ip address in DNS
`roundcube` is also enabled in webmails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer after 2 days:

**Symptoms**
The Mail tab is missing for a domain in Parallels Plesk.

**Cause**
The subscription was created before the mail server was installed. As a result, the service entry is missing in the database.

**Solution**

> http://kb.sp.parallels.com/en/120566

Comment: Yes, I got to that too, but it didn't work. I tried to install Plesk 12.5 but it moaned about Virtuozzo Container limit being exceeded. I suspect that if you originally installed Plesk on a virtual server part of the installation failed because of resource limits. It makes you wonder what else was silently broken :(

Answer (score 0):

Resolution 1: From Plesk User Interface

Step 1: Log into Plesk panel.

Step 2: Go in Tools & Settings option

Step 3: Click on Mail Tab.

Step 4: Click on Mail Server Settings and ensure that the option Enable mail management functions is on.

Resolution 2: from the command line

For linux (SSH):

```
#/usr/local/psa/bin/mail --update-service example.comd -status enabled -ignore-nonexistent-options
#/usr/local/psa/bin/mail --on example.com -ignore-nonexistent-options
#/usr/local/psa/bin/domain --info example.com | grep 'Mail service'
```

Mail service: On

For windows (CMD) :

```
"%plesk_dir%\bin\domain" --update example.com -mail_service true
"%plesk_dir%\bin\domain" --info example.com | findstr /C:"Mail service"
```

Mail service: On